# Purpose of ubuntu cloud image "admin" group?

Tags: 16.04, cloud, groups

I noticed that in the cloud image for xenial (http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/) there seems to be a group created by default named "admin". It does not seem to be present in 14.04 or in the non-cloud images for 16.04. Does anyone know its purpose?

This causes the useradd command to fail for a user named "admin" without the -g option specified i.e. adding that user "admin" into the pre-existing "admin" group. It would be good to know this group's purpose so I can determine if I should be disallowing the creation of a user named "admin" or if I should just add it to this pre-existing group.

Comment: Or don't create a user admin ;) The better way would be to create a user for every person so you can track all what they do in the logs by name.

Comment: We are shipping prepackaged images and the users boot them with an iso containing user information. There are scripts which read in that information from the iso and create users accordingly. It is those scripts which break on the "admin" username once we upgraded the base image to this ubuntu 16.04 cloud image. So its more a documentation thing - like I need to specify in the documentation that "admin" cannot be used as a username. Would be nice to explain why this is the case.